# Eclipse / STS with Needed Plugin

Tags: eclipse, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I want to install all the needed plugin's on my Eclipse installation and then generate a zip or exe which i could distribute to other developers, so that they dont have to reinstall the plugins.

I was wondering if there i a way to do this. Please pour in your thoughts and experience.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [mirrored update site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360424/how-to-create-an-eclipse-update-archive-from-an-online-update-site) as archive file on your machine and distribute that to the developers. The effort for doing this is very high, but your colleagues can install the plugins offline.

Alternatively you can just export a *description* of your installed plugins using File -> Export -> Install -> Installed plugins, which your colleagues can install using the same menus under File -> Import. That one is easy to do, but your colleagues need to be online afterwards, as they will install from the same update sites that you used.

I recommend starting with the second option.